# How to store json data to a variable in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to fetch the employee ID from the json file in the format as below in Cypress but its returning error as
`Cannot read property 'name' of null`

How can I retrieve the employee id for the user name "Devin Miller" ? Please help

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "role": "Software Engineer",
      "organization": "Google",
      "name": "Remi Arsenault",
      "emplyeeID":"526321",
      "project": "Stadia"
    },
    {
      "role": "Data Analyst",
      "organization": "Google",
      "emplyeeID": "526322",
      "name": "Devin Miller",
      "project": "Stadia"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my code

```
export function GetUserData(employeeName){     
    cy
      .fixture('users')
      .its('data')
      .then((users) => {     
        Users = users.find(user => user.name === employeeName);
      })
  }

export var Users = null;
```

now if I am trying to do the below then it is returning error

```
var employeeID = Users["Remi Arsenault"].emplyeeID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are having some bad expectations related to async vs snyc code.

Also, for accessing the fixture data you might try this instead of the `.its('data)` :

```js
cy.fixture('users').then((usersJson) => {
    let foundUser = usersJson.data.find(user => user.name === 'Remi Arsenault');
    let emloyeeID = foundUser.employeeID
    ... ['whatever else you want to do can go here inside the then callback.']
});
```